# Диспетчер автоматического резервирования информации с серверов ftp и почты

Tags: c++, ftp

Получил тему дипломной работы "Разработка диспетчера автоматического резервирования информации с серверов ftp и почты", которую я думаю написать на С++, но не знаю от чего оттолкнуться. Посоветуйте с чего начать, может план работы или исходниками, литературой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оттолкнись от задачи. Запусти ftpшный и почтовый сервер. И вперед и с песней писать программу, которая будет качать с них информацию. Как научишься, пишешь диспетчер, кторый будет автоматически запускать скачивание.

Почитать рекомендую про алгоритмы работы протокола FTP и протокола работы с почтовым сервером.

Comment: Буду пробовать